# XCode - compiling C and C++ files together, SWRevealController

Tags: xcode, swrevealviewcontroller, metaio

I am building app for iOS (I am really new to programming, so I basically cut-copy-paste  my way through this).
I want an app, that has slide menu [from here http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-sidebar-navigation-menu/] 
After clicking the screen "news frontpage" I want to load Metaio "HelloWorldTutorial". I made connections etc.
But I have a problem compiling this project together. IF I use "Compile sources as… " and pick "according to file type" I have an error from one of the header files "Lexical or Preprocessor issue 'cassert' file not found"
I googled it and solution is - compile everything as objective C++. 
So I switch to that, and now, I have errors in SWRevealController.m [which is ofc C file]
all Parse Issue, Semantic Issue, or ARC Semantic Issue. To which solution is, I should compile it as a C file.

What should I do?

Comment: You really need to backup and spend the tie to learn the basics such as the "C" language, Objective-C, Xcode, etc. The approach of just copy/paste is like trying to fly a 777 without having gone through flight school: lot's of crashed with no real understanding of why the plane crashed. (Do use a flight simulator, not a real 777.)

Comment: This is somethging I am asked to do, I am learining now Java/Android, and this is something I need to get done.